# Python seeded random produces different outputs on Linux and Windows

Tags: python

This is my Python script code:

```
import random,string

flag = "BNZQ:2m8807395d9os2156v70qu84sy1w2i6e"  
encflag = ""  
random.seed("random")  
for c in flag:  
  if c.islower():
    #rotate number around alphabet a random amount
    encflag += chr((ord(c)-ord('a')-random.randrange(0,26))%26 + ord('a'))
  elif c.isupper():
    encflag += chr((ord(c)-ord('A')-random.randrange(0,26))%26 + ord('A'))
  elif c.isdigit():
    encflag += chr((ord(c)-ord('0')-random.randrange(0,10))%10 + ord('0'))
  else:
    encflag += c
print "Unguessably Randomized Flag: "+encflag
```

I run it with Win10(Python 2.7.13) firstly, it produces a false output:

> TUPQ:0m8726993r0hm7952j01lv18ee5f5s0o

Then I run it with Kali Linux(Python 2.7.12), it produces a right output:

> FLAG:9b6098160b2ca5139c83fe29fd7c9e5d

Next I run it with Win7 VMware(Python 2.7.12), the output is same to Win10.

Is this the OS problem? I Google this problem and reading the Python Random Reference, but foung no result...
Thanks for your reading and help. Forgive my bad English..

Comment: This _should_ work.  I guess the issue here is that you are seeding the Mersenne twister with a string, which is the same as seeding it with the hash of that string, and strings may be subject to hash randomization depending on configuration.  Try seeding with an integer instead.

Comment: @VMRuiz The standard RNG in Python should be completely platform-independent.  It's a relatively standard Mersenne twister which is implemented in C and included in Python.  The `random.SystemRandom` class relies on the OS, but not the standard RNG.

Comment: The random.seed documentation says: *If a hashable object is given, deterministic results are only assured, when PYTHONHASHSEED is disabled." I'd check that one...

Comment: @Sven Marnach Thanks for your help. It works! When seeding with an integer, I got same output both with Windows and Linux. But this challenge asks to use the seed of `random`. Where could I change the configuration in windows?

Comment: @guidot Thanks for your help. I've seen it before. But I don't know how to close the PYTHONHASHSEED..